# MongoDB upsert in subdocument in array and return the updated subdocument

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
{ 
     "_id" : ObjectId(1234),
     "name": "foo", 
     "bars": [ 
         { "name": "n1", "myBool": true }, 
         { "name": "n2", "myBool": false }, 
         { "name": "n3", "myBool": false }
     ] 
}
```

I'd like to find the `name` (or the whole subdocument, it doesn't really matter) AND change `myBool` to `true` for the first subdocument in `bars` that is currently `false` for a given `_id` in an atomic operation. For example with the data above I'd like to return `n2` AND set `myBool` to `true` for `n2` in the document that has `_id` equal to `ObjectId(1234)`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Run the **[`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)** command with the parameter new set to true and thus returns the modified document rather than the original.

The update should use the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/) which identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. For this to work the array field must appear as part of the query document.

The output document has a `value` field  which contains the command's returned document:

```
var result = db.runCommand({
    "findAndModify": "collection",
    "query": { 
        "_id" : 1234, 
        "bars.myBool": false 
    },
    "update": { "$set": { "bars.$.myBool": true } },
    "new": true
});
printjson(result.value);
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : 1234,
    "name" : "foo",
    "bars" : [
        {
            "name" : "n1",
            "myBool" : true
        },
        {
            "name" : "n2",
            "myBool" : true
        },
        {
            "name" : "n3",
            "myBool" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can it be tweaked to only return the subdocument instead of the whole document? I.e. I'd like to know which subdocument (name) that was changed.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do it within an atomic update. You'd have to filter the array manually i.e. run two separate queries 1. to find the document with `"_id" : 1234, 
        "bars.myBool": false 
    }` and then run the above update which returns the modified document. When you get the two documents you can then find the difference in the `bars` array subdocuments.

Comment: Well unfortunately this won't work in a highly concurrent environment since two or more threads can do this concurrently. I.e. I can't first read and then compare the result since another thread might have updated "myBool" as well and then I don't know which one that was changed.

Comment: @Johan - if you want to do this atomically you could use `new: false`, inspect the document pre-update to know what will have been upserted, and infer the new document.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
May be this a work around, but fulfils your requirement, use the following query

```
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { "_id": 123456, "bars.myBool": false},
    update: {$set: {"bars.$.myBool": true}},
        fields: {
            "bars": {$elemMatch: {"myBool" : false }}
        }   
})
```

The hack is it returns the original document that is going to be modified.

It returns

```
{
    "_id" : 123456,
    "bars" : [
        {
            "name" : "n2",
            "myBool" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Where you can get the document that is being updated

so `result` contains array with single sub-document, through which you can get the name.

Read more about [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that I don't know the name. I want to get the name (and update myBool) in an atomic operation.

Comment: Sorry, for not understanding the OP, Once check the updated answer.